# how to tell when a dde response is complete?

Tags: dde

I'm talking to a DDE server I don't have very much documentation for using the NDde .NET library.  I've attached handlers for both the Advise and Disconnected events and am receiving data successfully.  I never see a Disconnected event raised nor do I see anything in the response stream that seems to signal that all the data has been returned.  So, two questions:  1) where can I find a intro guide to DDE?  There doesn't seem to be very much out there now regarding it.  And 2) am I thinking about this correctly?  Should the server tell me when it has sent all the data it intends to send for an Advise link in the data stream or by raising an event or do I have to estimate the number of responses that should be returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of the NDde library so maybe I can help.  It is a little late I know.  Anyway, the client and server exchange information in an agreed upon protocol.  So there is probably nothing you are doing wrong with the library.  You just need to know how the server works.  The `Disconnected` event will be raised when the conversation is terminated so that is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks much for the response.  and kudos on the library--without it, I couldn't even have attempted this.

Answer (score 0):

1) maybe here http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/ddeinfo.html you will find something useful (I understand MSDN it's not what you want)

Comment: Thanks, this looks helpful.  And, yep, I did find the MSDN doc a bit baffling.